# how to properly position an imageview in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I'm working on an app, which contains a text in the middle of the screen (a random quote) and a next button near the bottom of the screen. I have positioned the bottom in android studio; however, when run the app on my phone the button shows at the top left corner. How can I properly position the button? what properties do I need on my activity_main.xml file to correctly position the image? 
[screen capture of app in devices](http://pctechtips.org/images/screen.png)
Thanks
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    tools:context="com.example.george.radonquote.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_quote"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.41" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nexticon"
        android:onClick="getRandomQuote"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="403dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="140dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my answer to this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552260/buttons-not-in-place/46552928

Comment: I changed it to RelativeLayout and use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

I changed the layout to RelativeLayout and use the following for ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/nexticon"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="getRandomQuote"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```